# What is the difference between apt-daily.timer and apt-daily-upgrade.timer

Tags: unattended-upgrades

I can't find what is the difference between these 2 files.

What does `apt-daily.timer` and `apt-daily-upgrade.timer` trigger?

My guess is that:

- `apt-daily.timer` trigger `apt update`

And

- `apt-daily-upgrade.timer` trigger `apt -y upgrade`

but I can't find it written anywhere clearly in these terms.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Documented on [Debian](https://wiki.debian.org/UnattendedUpgrades#Modifying_download_and_upgrade_schedules_.28on_systemd.29):

- Used for **downloads**: `/lib/systemd/system/apt-daily.timer`.
- Used for **upgrades**: `/lib/systemd/system/apt-daily-upgrade.timer`

The timers control the `apt-daily.service` and `apt-daily-upgrade.service`. The first execute `/usr/lib/apt/apt.systemd.daily` script with `update` argument, the second will execute `/usr/lib/apt/apt.systemd.daily` with `install` argument.

Answer (score 1):

You have to compare their filecontents locally or online:

> https://salsa.debian.org/apt-team/apt/-/blob/main/debian/apt-daily.timer :
>
> ```
> Description=Daily apt download activities
> ```

> https://salsa.debian.org/apt-team/apt/-/blob/main/debian/apt-daily-upgrade.timer :
>
> ```
> Description=Daily apt upgrade and clean activities
> ```

Both trigger the [`apt.systemd.daily`](https://salsa.debian.org/apt-team/apt/-/blob/main/debian/apt.systemd.daily) script - the first runs [update](https://salsa.debian.org/apt-team/apt/-/blob/main/debian/apt-daily.service), the second runs [install](https://salsa.debian.org/apt-team/apt/-/blob/main/debian/apt-daily-upgrade.service) (using `unattended-upgrade` script).

Comment: Why is there no `Unit=` in the timer file corresponding to the service file that its suppose to run? Where is the mapping?

Comment: https://salsa.debian.org/apt-team/apt/-/blob/main/debian/apt-daily.service and https://salsa.debian.org/apt-team/apt/-/blob/main/debian/apt-daily-upgrade.service

Comment: @HussainNagri a .timer unit has an implicit dependency on the corresponding .service unit of the same name.